# "On the other hand" vs. "On the other side"

Tags: sentence-construction, relative-adverbs

Consider this scenario:

There are two phases A and B (e.g water on one side and oil on the other side).

[image]

I wrote:

> Compared with the neat IL/water, the amount of water increased from 0.2 to about 0.24 ml in the IL phase.  **On the other side/hand**, the amount of IL increased, from x to y in the water phase.

Can I use "on the other hand" here? I guess "No"

Can I use "on the other side"? Are there other alternatives for such cases? or maybe "from the other side"?

Comment: Could you explain your thinking on the choices. I don't think either one is OK. "on the other hand" is point/counterpoint, and "on the other side" requires at least two sides. It would be better if you could paraphrase in a non-technical worded example, as the meaning of "phase" is unclear. Perhaps could you consider "At the same time,..."?

Comment: @user3169 I guess I explained it. Anyway, I added a picture to elaborate it more. "Phase" is just mean a state of a material (solid, liquid, gas). You can regard it as two materials in contact with each other.